# Should I split up a complex query into one to filter results and one to gather data?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm designing a central search function in a PHP web application. It is focused around a single table and each result is exactly one unique ID out of that table. Unfortunately there are a few dozen tables related to this central one, most of them being 1:n relations. Even more unfortunate, I need to join quite a few of them. A couple to gather the necessary data for displaying the results, and a couple to filter according to the search criteria.

I have been mainly relying on a single query to do this. It has a lot of joins in there and, as there should be exactly one result displayed per ID, it also works with rather complex subqueries and group by uses. It also gets sorted according to a user-set sort method and there's pagination in play as well done by the use of LIMIT.

Anyways, this query has become insanely complex and while I nicely build it up in PHP it is a PITA to change or debug. I have thus been considering another approach, and I'm wondering just how bad (or not?) this is for performance before I actually develop it. The idea is as follows:

- run one less complex query only filtering according the search parameters. This means less joins and I can completely ignore group by and similar constructs, I will just "SELECT DISTINCT item_id" on this and get a list of IDs
- then run another query, this time only joining in the tables I need to display the results (only about 1/4 of the current total joins) using ... WHERE item_id IN (....), passing the list of "valid" IDs gathered in the first query.

Note: Obviously the IN () could actually contain the first query in full instead of relying on PHP to build up a comma-separated list).

How bad will the IN be performance-wise? And how much will it possibly hurt me that I can not LIMIT the first query at all? I'm also wondering if this is a common approach to this or if there are more intelligent ways to do it.  I'd be thankful for any input on this :)

Note to clarify: We're not talking about a few simple joins here. There is even (simple) hierarchical data in there where I need to compare the search parameter against not only the items own data but also against its parent's data. In no other project I've ever worked on have I encountered a query close to this complexity. And before you even say it, yes, the data itself has this inherent complexity, which is why the data model is complex too.

Comment: Build both and measure the performance impact.  As a bonus, you'll gain a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Do you have control of the data model? I ask because you could consider pre-aggregating some of the structures you need for this use case with an ETL tool and simplify the query a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

My experience has shown that using the `WHERE IN(...)` approach tends to be slower.  I'd go with the joins, but make sure you're joining on the smallest dataset possible first.  Reduce down the simple main table, then join onto that.  Make sure your most complex joins are saved to the end to minimize the rows required to search.  Try to join on indexes wherever possible to improve speed, and ditch wildcards in JOINS where possible.

But I agree with Andomar, if you have the time build both and measure.